# DOTNET Core - Persisting a database name for a session

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

It was suggested to use [this](https://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-core-multi-tenancy-data-isolation-with-entity-framework) concept to run a multitenant separate database which appears to be the simplest option regarding configuring the DBContext.

[This](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/848111/Multi-Tenancy-System-With-Separate-Databases-in-MV) option although out of date uses a separate catalog database to store each tenants details including the database name.

I would like to use the second option so I can update the database easily with new clients. However, I note that every time I would send a request in I would have to access the catalog database to retrieve the database name again in order to configure the DBContext. This has performance issues in that I have now two database calls - one to configure the context and one for the actual data request.

I note that there is a `httpContext.Session.SetString(xxx, yyy)` and  `HttpContext.Session.GetString("xxx")` option that you could use to store the database name for the session.

My question is, is this a valid option for temporarily storing the database name so I dont have to do a database call everytime I get a request? Is it safe? Is there a better way to do this with a catalog database(holds user name and database connection details)?

Comment: What authentication framework are you using?  Via something like ASP.NET Identity, you could determine this at the time of login and store as a claim.  That would remove the need to hit the DB to determine the correct context, and should play nice with any DI as well.

Comment: Its a SPA implementation with Aurelia at the front end. As such I am using a JWT to manage authentication.